# Anchor element's pathname returns undefined in Rhino with env.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, rhino, envjs

I have run into [an issue](https://github.com/guardian/sbt-jasmine-plugin/issues/17) that I believe is rooted in the implementation of anchor tags in Rhino.  Although I am utilizing [env.js](http://www.envjs.com/), I suspect perhaps I am not configuring something correctly.

In particular, my issue occurs while I am attempting to write unit tests against code written for an angularjs application.  When I include `angular.js` (versions 1.2.1 to present), I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot call method "charAt" of undefined`

I am convinced the error is the result of [this call](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/736c8fbbae57a209f4ba570e38cc3bd0745a9569/src/ng/urlUtils.js#L86) to `urlParsingNode.pathname` since a `console.log` call reveals that the `pathname` object is undefined.

I traced the instantiation of the `urlParsingNode` to [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/736c8fbbae57a209f4ba570e38cc3bd0745a9569/src/ng/urlUtils.js#L9) where we see that it is the result of a call to `document.createElement("a");`  Further down, we see that they set the `href` attribute in [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/736c8fbbae57a209f4ba570e38cc3bd0745a9569/src/ng/urlUtils.js#L75) in hopes that the created anchor tag will utilize the browser to correctly parse the URL.

I have to believe I'm not the first to attempt JS unit testing for angular via Rhino, but thus far I've not successfully Googled myself to a solution.  Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see the same error with Angular 1.2.7, having based my project structure on a colleague's Angular 1.1.5 project. Though I may have inadvertently introduced the error as my project is somewhat different. Hope someone answers here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it and fixed it.  The `pathname` getter/setter simply was undefined for `HTMLAnchorElement` in `env.js`.

I submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/envjs/env-js/pull/34), but unfortunately the project looks all but abandoned.  I also couldn't figure out how to build it out to a single file.  It appears perhaps someone has taken it upon themselves to break it apart into `require.js` modules.  Not a battle worth fighting for my use case.

So for anyone else who hits this issue, I have the code you need below.  It belongs in the `HTMLAnchorElement.prototype`.  In my copy of `env.js` 1.2, this prototype begins on line 8075.  I added the following at line 8118.

```
get pathname() {
  var uri = Envjs.urlsplit(this.href);
  return uri.path;
},
set pathname(val) {
  var uri = Envjs.urlsplit(this.href);
  uri.path = val
  this.href(uri.urlunsplit(uri));
},
```

FYI, my particular issue is resolved with [this pull request](https://github.com/guardian/sbt-jasmine-plugin/pull/18).