# jQuery mobile + angularjs + phonegap android script errors

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, cordova

I am creating a phonegap application which is using jQuery mobile and angularjs.

I downloaded latest version of both frameworks. When I run application on android jelly bean machine I am getting whole bunch of errors, finally application does not show any output.

If I try to run same application (with commenting out cordova js) on desktop chrome or IE totally works fine there is no single problem.

I have set up like this;

[image]

and I am getting the following errors;

[image]

Is there any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of Angular JS you are using? It's a known issue . You can find the details here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4776. SO also has a somewhat same link [Anchor element's pathname returns undefined in Rhino with env.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028520/anchor-elements-pathname-returns-undefined-in-rhino-with-env-js). Just see this. Hope u will get some help from there.